# List returning only one value repeatedly

Tags: java, mysql

I have a table which contains columns full_name & department.I have written a query like this

```
 String query ="select full_name from users where department='QS'";
         ps=con.prepareStatement(query);
          rs=ps.executeQuery();
          while(rs.next()){
              joborderbean.setQs(rs.getString(1));

              list.add(joborderbean);
```

i have two full names with the department name QS. But the list returning only one name two times.

Please help me.

Comment: You need to instantiate a new instance of the type of `joborderbean`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a new object in each iteration of the loop :

```
      while(rs.next()){
          joborderbean = new WhateverClassItIs();
          joborderbean.setQs(rs.getString(1));

          list.add(joborderbean);
```